# when i run the code it cant find the model in main.js but app.js is connected through am i suposed to use only '.' insted of'../shared'?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

the error

./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/MainComponent' in 'C:\Users\TiZuM\Desktop\NucampFolder-copy\3-React\nucampsite\src'

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import './App.css';
```

main.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import Directory from './DirectoryComponent';
import { CAMPSITES } from '../shared/campsites';
import CampsiteInfo from './CampsiteInfoComponent';
```

Comment: do you have deafult export ?

Comment: i dont think so